# Payment Request API - Basic Card on Safari

Tags: safari, payment-request-api

I am trying to implement Payment Request API on a project I'm working on. I'm only using `basic-card` payment method. When I call `canMakePayment()` it correctly resolves to `true` in Chrome in situations that it should be `true`, but it never resolves to `true` in Safari. Then I read something interesting in the [webkit blog](https://webkit.org/blog/8182/introducing-the-payment-request-api-for-apple-pay/),

> Safari only supports the Apple Pay payment method, but other browsers
>   might support additional payment methods.

If that means what I think it means, then I cannot use `basic-card` payment method in Safari. Only Apple Pay.

Can someone please shed some light in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed the case. Safari only supports Apple Pay at the moment. It doesn't support basic card, unfortunately :(
https://webkit.org/blog/8182/introducing-the-payment-request-api-for-apple-pay/